# how can i implement captcha v3 in a registration form in grails 2.5.6?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I need to implement a captcha with v3 in grails but I'm relatively new to implementing captchas has anyone ever implemented it in grails 2.5.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have used google recaptcha in contact us form.

I am using grails 2.2.

In the contact us gsp.

put this in head

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

where you would like captcha to show

```
<div id="captcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="${grailsApplication.config.captchaSiteKey}"></div>
```

put captchasitekey in config.groovy

```
captchaSiteKey = "234234lkjh234kjhdsf98sdflhjsdf"
captchaSecretKey = "12121234jh234kjhdsf98sdflhjsdf"
```

create your keys in google recaptcha admin console

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/

contact us submit button

```
<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="sendRequest()" class="button"/>
```

Javascript code

```
<g:javascript>

            function sendRequest(){


                var email_string = $('input[name="email"]').val();
                var body_string = $('textarea[name="body"]').val();
                var cap_response = $('textarea[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').val();


                var replying = "${params['s']}"
                var idd = "${params['i']}"

                if(email_string && body_string){

                  $.ajax('<g:createLink controller="public" action="sendMessage"/>', {
                        type:"post",
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data:{body: body_string, email: email_string, reply: replying, id: idd, recap_response: cap_response},
                        success: function(data) {


                            $('#body').val("");
                            $('#email').val("");


                            alert("Thanks for contacting us! We will respond promptly.");


                        },
                        error: function(xhr){
                            alert('Sorry there was a problem sending message. Please try again!'); //<----when no data alert the err msg

                        }
                    });

                }
                else{


                    alert("Please make sure you enter your email and message before sending us message.")
                }



            }



</g:javascript>
```

Server side

def sendMessage(){

```
def res = params['recap_response']

HttpURLConnection post = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify").openConnection());

String urlParameters = "secret=${grailsApplication.config.captchaSecretKey}&response=${res}";
byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

post.setRequestMethod("POST")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
post.getOutputStream().write(postData);
def postRC = post.getResponseCode();

def recaptchaOK = false


if(postRC.equals(200)) {

    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

    def resp = jsonSlurper.parseText(post.getInputStream().getText())

    recaptchaOK = resp.success

}


if(!recaptchaOK){

    render "Captcha was wrong. Please try again!"
    return
}
```

This is the documentation i referred to implement mine.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

hope this helps!